# SVN Change Notifier

Tags: svn, notifications

Anyone knows of an good and configurable application that would notify users of changes on either certain repositories/folders/files on SVN?

Answer (score 0):

I use http://tools.tortoisesvn.net/CommitMonitor.html

Answer (score 0):

Subversion also supports "hook scripts" which run when certain events occur in a repository. A post-commit hook script could send email, call an API, send an SMS message... whatever you need. See "Implementing Repository Hooks" in [SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.reposadmin.create.html).